# How to plot the imaginary part of $\tan(x)^{\cos(x)}$ on the $xy$-plane?

Tags: plotting, complex

So recently, I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4824538/is-my-thought-process-for-calculating-lim-x-to-pi-2-tanx-cosx-co) question on Math.SE on if my thought process on how to solve the limit $\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)^-}\tan(x)^{\cos(x)}$ was correct, and actually, while I was solving this, I was trying to plot the imaginary part of said equation in Mathematica for practice.

I do have code for plotting the real-value part

```mathematica
Plot[Tan[x]^Cos[x],{x,-5,5}]
```

which does work as intended, however I'm confused as to how to get the imaginary plot of this function.

I have tried using

```
ComplexPlot[Tan[x]^Cos[x],{x,-5,5}]
```

but it returns the following errors:

```
ComplexPlot: Corners for x in {x,-5,5} must have distinct machine-precision real and imaginary parts.
ComplexPlot: Corners for x in {x,-5,5} must have distinct machine-precision real and imaginary parts.
ComplexPlot: Corners for x in {x,-5,5} must have distinct machine-precision real and imaginary parts.
General: Further output of ComplexPlot::plld will be suppressed during this calculation.
ComplexPlot: Corners for x in {x,-5,5} must have distinct machine-precision real and imaginary parts.
ComplexPlot: Corners for x in {x,-5,5} must have distinct machine-precision real and imaginary parts.
Out[6]= ComplexPlot[Tan[x]^Cos[x],{x,-5,5}]
```

[image]

I managed to fix this by adding an imaginary part to my bounds (my current code so far)

```
ComplexPlot[Tan[x]^Cos[x],{x,-5-5i,5+5i}]
```

which returns this

[image]

which looks cool, but it's not what I'm trying to do.

What I'm trying to do is this is plot the imaginary part of $\tan(x)^{\cos(x)}$ on the $xy$-plane like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5Btan%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2Ccos%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%5D) (ignore the blue line):

[image]

although I don't know how to fix my code from here. So my question is:

#### How do I plot the imaginary part of $\tan(x)^{\cos(x)}$ on the $xy$-plane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[Tan[x]^Cos[x]]], {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, {-5, 5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Enough `Plot[Im[Tan[x]^Cos[x]], {x, 0, 2*Pi}]`.

Answer (score 2):

Since V 12.0 there is [ReImPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReImPlot.html)

```
ReImPlot[Tan[x]^Cos[x], {x, -5, 5},
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> {"Expressions", "ReIm"},
 PlotRange -> {All, {-5, 5}}]
```

[image]

We also have [AbsArgPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsArgPlot.html) which generates a plot of `Abs[f]` colored by `Arg[f]`

```
AbsArgPlot[Tan[x]^Cos[x], {x, -5, 5},
 Epilog ->
  {Dashed,
   {InfiniteLine[{Pi, 0}, {Pi, 1000}],
    InfiniteLine[{-Pi, 0}, {-Pi, 1000}]}},
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]